# Convert date & time field from American to English - Oracle Business Intelligence

Tags: oracle, date

I am building a report in Oracle Business Intelligence and the output of the date is currently American, and also has a time on it - so output formats, for example '11/29/2016 3:58:26 PM'

I am trying to get the output from the report (as it is sent on a schedule everyday) to be an English date format 'DD/MM/YYYY' - time is irrelevant, can be included or not.

I have tried a few different things, but no success - can anyone help?

The column name is "Candidate Latest CSW Date"."Candidate Latest CSW Date" where the data is being pulled from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Date-typed values do not have formats. If the value comes from the database as a date instead of a string, you only need to specify the display format in your report. If it comes as a string, it's a bug in the query or the database. Dates shouldn't be stored or retrieved as strings

Answer (score 1):

you can use TO_CHAR(var_name, 'DD/MM/YYYY') if i understand your question...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answers etc above; tried all but didn't get what I needed.  I did manage to sort this by using the below:

cast("Candidate Latest CSW Date"."Candidate Latest CSW Date" as varchar(40))

If I am perfectly honest, I am unsure why this worked - but it switched the Day and Month around to be read as English date